# Completely remove XCode Target

Tags: ios, xcode

How do I completely remove an XCode target such that if I create a new target with the same name, none of the previous files/settings associated with it will remain?

Comment: In xcode 5.1, select the xcode project in the project navigator. In the main area, Click the tiny disclosure arrow enclosed in a rectangle in the same menu that has "Build Settings, Build Phases, Build Rules." You can delete targets there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you'll have to make a lot of manual work to do that:

- open .xcodeproj with alt-click - Show Package Content
- open project.pbxproj with the text editor
  Now look for `/* Begin PBXNativeTarget section */`, you'll find the list of the targets below.
  Here comes the part which will likely make you create the new project - there're so many cross-references by identifiers to be analyzed. You'll have to find yourself what you want to remove there.
- remove xcuserdata to clear users preferences for the project

Comment: Thanks - this gets rid of a target in XCode. My reason for asking appears to be related to an iOS bug. CLLocationManager never stops location services when I build with a particular target name. If I change the target name everything works fine. I found that after wiping the device, the problem disappears. There must be some cached files from previous builds hanging around on the device.

Comment: @Ralfonso Oh, you now know too much about how apple does store the location history :)

Answer (score 1):

In xCode Version 9.2 (9C40b) onward you should be able to just right click the target you want to remove. xCode will do all the heavy lifting with file membership etc behind the scenes.

Comment: Have you tried it out? It's an old question (and Xcode build), but if you can provide a verified procedure for the most recent version, it'll be great for others who run into this issue in the future.

Comment: Yes I have in the latest prod build (9.2)